# how to show alert in the redirected page?

Tags: javascript, php

in index.php I have 3 buttons (add, delete, edit)

if I click to delete it will redirect to the delete page query (delete.php)

after delete success, the page redirects to index.php and the sweet alert2 will popup with a success message (deleted successfully)

if I add a user the msg will change to added successfully

it depends on where I redirect to index.php

so what I can do?

Comment: https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-flash-messages/

Comment: this is a helpful comment, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution1

Before redirecting, you should create a session object and save the alert messages in sessions.

```
start_session()

$_SESSION["alert"] = ["type" => "success", "message" => "User deleted successfully"];
```

On index.php page

On a index.php page, check if there’s a flash/alert message. If so, output and delete it.

```
if (isset($_SESSION["alert"]))
{

echo 

"<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible'>
                <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
                <h4><i class='icon fa fa-check'></i> Alert!</h4>
                 $_SESSION["alert"]
              </div>";
  
unset($_SESSION["flash"]);
}
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

While redirecting from delete.php/edit.php to index.php you can pass some query params.

Redirection from delete.php will look like index.php?msg="deleted successfully";

Redirection from edit.php will look like index.php?msg="added successfully"

In index.php you can read the query string msg and display the alert box

Here is the refs to get query string param.

[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)